# Push ViewController in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a general question: I have set up a `TabBar` in my app. When I click on item 1, the TabBar shows a `ViewController` (VC 1) embedded in a `NavigationController`. This VC is supposed to push another VC (VC 2) when the user logs out (using firebase   and `addStateDidChangeListener`). It works great : When I log out the VC1 push VC 2. However when I click again on the item 1 on the tab bar. Guess what? I can see VC 1 while there is no user. I think I have to dismiss VC 1 somehow but I do not know how to implement this function. Can you help me?

Comment: A little bit unclear. Can you explain it better?

Comment: have you tried self.dismiss on VC1 ? call it wherever you are calling to leave VC1, vc1 should then be dismissed and as long as you are not segueing back to it, then VC2 should appear

Comment: Can you show some code? maybe how you load your TabBar and your navigation controller. But In general, you don't need view controller in the stack if you don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Changing view controllers in the navigation controller

When logout button is tapped remove the VC1 from navigation controller and add VC2

```
if var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
    viewControllers.removeLast()
    viewControllers.append(VC2())
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
}
```

When logging in again in `VC2` again change view controllers

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([VC1()], animated: true)
```

## Changing view controllers in tab bar controller

Logout

```
if var viewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
    let newVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC2())
    newVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Log In", image: nil, tag: 0)
    viewControllers.removeFirst()
    viewControllers.insert(newVC, at: 0)
    self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = viewControllers
}
```

Login

```
if var viewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
    let newVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC1())
    newVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: nil, tag: 0)
    viewControllers.removeFirst()
    viewControllers.insert(newVC, at: 0)
    self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = viewControllers
}
```

Comment: It is not really working for me since my item 1 image in my tab bar disappears and I have now black screen. I have tried to change the remove and insert position (from 0 to 1 for example) but same result.

Comment: it was working until I click on the log out button and have the following error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UINavigationControllers are not allowed in a navigation controller!'

Comment: I have now a problem with the TableView in VC1. It seems that it does not find the DataSource: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: @ RajeshKumar R When I start the app, I am already log out; and when I click on the item in the TabBar the app crashes. I can see the VC2 but it seems there is an error with the DataSource of VC 1..strange...

Comment: in fact we are almost there. It is almost working. When I start the app and I am already log on, VC 1 shows. When I log out, VC2 shows. Very good! BUT when I log in again. VC 1 does not show

Comment: I have used your code in both VC and it works great : if var viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
    viewControllers.removeLast()
    viewControllers.append(VC2())
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
}

Comment: thank you very much for your guidance and perseverance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can override window rootviewcontroller new tabbar controller. So in future you dont have any bugs with new development (new screen hierarchy).

```
    //Login
    let navigation = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc1)
    let tabVC = UITabBarController()
    tabVC.viewControllers?.append(navigation)
    self.appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = navigation

    //Logout
    let navigation = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc2)
    let tabVC = UITabBarController()
    tabVC.viewControllers?.append(navigation)
    self.appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = navigation
```

Answer (score -1):

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

```
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    print("didReceive2: ", userInfo)
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    
        //        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotificationName.openRaceDAyTipsTab, object: nil)
    
    let application = UIApplication.shared
    
    if(application.applicationState == .active) {
        print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in foreground")
    }
    
    if(application.applicationState == .inactive) {
        print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in background")
    }
    
    guard let rootViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController else {
        return
    }
    print("got active scene")
    
    
        // handle the push notification here
    if let articleId = userInfo["articleId"] as? String {
            // use the articleId in your app logic
            // Create an instance of ArticlesDetailViewController
        let articlesDetailVC = ArticlesDetailViewController.instantiateHome()
        articlesDetailVC.articlesId = articleId
        
        if let tabBarVC = rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
           let navVC = tabBarVC.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
            navVC.pushViewController(articlesDetailVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    completionHandler()
}
```